Sending a \newpage from a quarto R chunk, when using a plot loop
I'm working in Quarto 1.4 and want to send plots to a pdf output. I'm trying to mirror the behavior of base graphics from the R console, in which I set a page layout to 2x2 plots (par(mfrow=c(2,2)) but might have 8 plots or 12 plots or > 4. From the R console once I get past 4 plots, the plot window is blanked and the next 4 are plotted, then the next, etc. What I'm wonder is whether I can replicate that behavior in Quarto rendering to pdf, for example I count the plots and after the 4th I want to do the equivalent of a new page so the next four will be on p 2, etc. Currently the plots > 4 are put to the right side of the first 4 and off the page. I'll accept that I may be asking too much but if this is possible... Thanks in advance for either yay or nay. The code below doesn't work but it gives the gist of what I'm trying to do.
```
---
title: Test case
format: 
  titlepage-pdf: 
    listings: false
---  
```{r}
pagebreak <- function() {
  
  if(knitr::is_latex_output()){
    cat('pagebreak\n')
    return("\\newpage")
  }else{
    return('<div style="page-break-before: always;" />')
  }
}
```


```{r}
#| label: fig-pb
#| fig-cap: try to create new page of plots
#| echo: false
#| include: true
#| results: asis
#| fig-pos: center
#| fig-width: 6.5
#| fig-asp: 1.5
#| out-width: 6.5in



  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  for(i in 1:8){
  x <- rnorm(10000,-0.75,1)
  hist(x)
  if(i == 4) pagebreak()
  }



